# How can I change the background and text color of an element with a CSS transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'd like to change the background color and text color in the following `div`:

#### HTML

```html
<div class="readmore">
  <a href="#">readmore</a>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.readmore{
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #FFCC66;
    color: #336699;
}

.readmore:hover{
    background-color: #336699;
    color: #FFCC66;

    transition: all 1s;
}
```

When I focus `.readmore`, the background color changes but the text "readmore" doesn't change color... Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your A tag has it's own color property. Changing it on the div doesn't automaticly work for the A tag, but you have to inherit the necessary properties.

```
.readmore a
{
    background-color:inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```